# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la estructura de una columna en oracle report builder?

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql, report, numberformat

Actualmente estoy manejando 'oracle report builder 11g' para la modificación de un reporte, el reporte se crea por medio de una consulta 'PL/SQL' pero debido a unos cambios existía una columna "Total" con un estructura number(9,2) y tuve que cambiarlo a number(12,6), se realizo el cambio en la base de datos pero no me deja cambiar la estructura en el oracle report builder y no sé como se puede hacer para modificarla ya que no es editable el "ancho" en las opciones donde se muestra la estructura agradezco cualquier ayuda y recomendación.

Answer (score 1):

En el apartado de modelo de datos de Oracle Reports, en la paleta de herramientas debes de hacer click en **Columna de Formula (f(x))**, para crear una funcion. En esa funcion creada le das doble click y vas a la opcion de "Fórmula PL/SQL" ahi pones tu codigo que puede ser el siguiente :                `function CF_1Formula return Number is v_total number(12,6); begin select total into v_total from tabla where condicion1 = :P_PARAMETRO1; return v_total; end;`

Después solo tienes que crear un campo vació en tu diseño del reports, a ese campo le das **F4** y una de las opciones es **ORIGEN** ahí buscas y seleccionas tu **FUNCIÓN CREADA**.